# Diff two CSVs by specific columns, output matching rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am comparing two CSV files. I need to know which rows match by comparing specific columns. The output needs to be the rows that match.

**Data:**

CSV 1:

```
name, age, occupation
Alice,51,accountant
John,23,driver
Peter,32,plumber
Jose,50,doctor
```

CSV 2:

```
name, age, occupation
Alice,51,dentist
Ted,43,carpenter
Peter,32,plumber
Jose,50,doctor
```

**Desired Ouput:**

Rather than returning a boolean, I would like to output the matching rows when only comparing the name and age columns:

```
Alice,51,accountant 
Alice,51,dentist 
Peter,32,plumber
Jose,50,doctor
```

**Code:**

I am comparing the two CSVs to see if the columns in the 'columns_to_compare_test' list match. I return a boolean, true or false.

```
# read two csv files into dataframes
df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', encoding='UTF-8')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep=',', encoding='UTF-8')

# compare only the name and age columns
columns_to_compare_test = ['name', 'age']

# print true or false
print(df1[columns_to_compare_test].equals(df2[columns_to_compare_test]))

# output: false
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# load csv
df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', encoding='UTF-8')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test2.csv', sep=',', encoding='UTF-8')

# look for matching rows
filter = ['name', 'age']
filter = df1[filter].eq(df2[filter]).all(axis=1)
df1 = df1[filter].append(df2[filter])

# remove duplicates e.g. Jose
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()

print(df1.head())
```

You are using equals to check if the row is in the other df on an element basis. `all()` will make sure, that both `age` and `name` match.

You can finally use the resulting series to select the relevant rows in both dfs and append them. This will result in the following output:

```
    name  age  occupation
0  Alice   51  accountant
2  Peter   32     plumber
3   Jose   50      doctor
0  Alice   51     dentist
```

Please let me know, if you wanted to achieve a different effect.